# Post de formulário não funciona em Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, post, request

Eu estou tentando enviar os dados de um formulário pelo método POST, porem ele não esta indo de jeito algum

Segue o meu código

```
// routes.php
Route::any('/', function()
{
    echo Request::getMethod();   // Aqui esta sempre retornando GET
    return View::make( 'login' );
});

// view/login.blade.php
<form action="{{URL::to('/')}}" method="post">
    <input name="login" type="text"/><br/>
    <input type="password" name="senha" id=""/><br/>
    {{ Form::submit('Enviar') }}
</form>
```

Independente se a tela foi carregado pelo link ou pelo click do submit, o retorno do Request::getMethod() está sendo sempre GET, consequentemente, não tem nenhum dado no $_POST, porque acontece isso?

Comment: Não acho que direcionar a Route para `any` seja a melhor alternativa. Tem alguma razão para não usar um `Route::get` e um `Route::post` ?

Comment: Porque estou tentando fazer a tela de Login, por questão de segurança, acho melhor usar o POST

Comment: Lai, acredito que é algo assim que você quer fazer, certo? https://gist.github.com/gmsantosxl/feaedd41b7cdaff6304c

Comment: Exatamente! mas eu estou fazendo router separado, porque eu tentei com Route::any e não consegui, por falta de conhecimento, tenho medo de ser problemas tecnicas, então resolvi fazer separados, mas mesmo assim, o Request::getMethod() está me retornando sempre GET, sabe porque acontece isso?

Answer (score 1):

Request::getMethod() retorna o método (verbo) http utilizado no request. Estranho estar retornando GET se você colocou post no seu form html.

Para recuperar parâmetros enviados no request, deve utilizar outros comandos:

```
Request::all() // retorna um array com todos os parâmetros
```

Answer (score 0):

você chegou a dar f12 e ver se o post está sendo enviado mesmo, eu acho que sim.
O que está de errado no seu código é o

```
Request::getMethod();
```

Pensa comigo... Se o method do seu formulário é post, por que você acha que buscando getMethod() irá retornar algo além de get?

eu particularmente utilizo Input::all(), mas já vi codigos utilizando Request::all();

Ai basta você decidir o que é melhor para você

Comment: Pode ser falta de conhecimento meu, mas a função Request::getMethod() não é para retornar o método que foi executado?